# Conlangs based on Proto-Indo-European (PIE)?

Tags: history, natural-languages

Have there been any attempts to create a language based on Proto-Indo-European (PIE)?

Of course PIE has had an effect on other languages, and through them ended up in many a posteriori conlangs as well. What I mean is whether there have been any attempts to create a usable language based on what we know of PIE and filling in the blanks with conlangery.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/380/113) list some.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your question a bit: are you looking for conlangs which were developed _from_ PIE (e.g. development of an alternative history in which there’s another branch of Indo-European languages), or languages which attempt to “complete” PIE in an artistic fashion?

Answer (score 10):

Academia Prisca published [Modern Indo-European](https://academiaprisca.org/en/indoeuropean/) as a revival of a late stage of the Indo-European language (Northwest Indo-European, billed as the ancestor of Italo-Celtic, Germanic and Balto-Slavic). [Resources](https://academiaprisca.org/en/resources/) published for learning include a grammar, syntax, conjugator, vocabulary, lessons and texts. Since it is meant as a modern revival, it introduces neologisms (such as *read* and *write*), but as far as I can tell, the entire lexicon is derived from cognate languages.